# change table based on selected value from database in JSP

Tags: java, html, css, jsp, jstl

I need to change the values displayed in the timetable based on the room I select from the dropdown list but I don't know how to do it.

The code for dropdown list is:

[select option list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8zId.png)

And on the same page, the code for the timetable:

[timetable JSP page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQvgN.png)

Right now it shows all values from the database regardless of the selected room.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not post images of your code here, but paste the minimal code needed to reproduce your problem. When the images gets taken down from imgur, this question will become unreadable. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

AJAX(Asynchronous Javascript and XML) can do this for you. AJAX allows for the updating of contents within an HTML object without reloading the page. W3Schools and the JQuery reference both have lots of helpful info on the matter.